# Encrypt in C# using RSACryptoServiceProvide and decrypt using openssl_private_decrypt in PHP

Tags: c#, php

I spent whole day for trying to get it work but no luck:(

I use these code in C# for encryption:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
rsaParam.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCwlhAsNcNCDRgzCc49u/0iSDrdJn7yoiH/HHipbQp0QSejzg/48mMA6wb32OPQ7qzBgJNvwiQbMvi89BvGNAJ9K8vM0RW7WOqtnb/8IK9BAJVtEwJ3vvKTf5EluiUgWVbGYpWPjbl/lsD3/hRTR0uF46h7q4OlARxOupl9xVS2wQIDAQAB");
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
string msg = "This is a test.";
byte[] encValue = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg), true);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(encValue));
```

This is the PHP code I use to decrypt.

```
// Read key
$fp = fopen($KeyPath,"r");
$Key = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted, openssl_get_privatekey($Key, "123456"));
```

The private key I used(Passphase "123456"):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,16B167A1F1E4E61E
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am not familiar with encryption, can some one please tell how to get it work?
PS: I think the code in php is fine since I tested the code seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for days and finally figured out myself:)
I am loading the parameters in the wrong way.

According to the RSA Public key structures(PEM):

`MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCwlhAsNcNCDRgzCc49u/0iSDrdJn7yoiH/HHipbQp0QSejzg/48mMA6wb32OPQ7qzBgJNvwiQbMvi89BvGNAJ9K8vM0RW7WOqtnb/8IK9BAJVtEwJ3vvKTf5EluiUgWVbGYpWPjbl/lsD3/hRTR0uF46h7q4OlARxOupl9xVS2wQIDAQAB`

Which I split the string into 3 parts(base64 encoded):

Header

`MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC`

Modulus:

`wlhAsNcNCDRgzCc49u/0iSDrdJn7yoiH/HHipbQp0QSejzg/48mMA6wb32OPQ7qzBgJNvwiQbMvi89BvGNAJ9K8vM0RW7WOqtnb/8IK9BAJVtEwJ3vvKTf5EluiUgWVbGYpWPjbl/lsD3/hRTR0uF46h7q4OlARxOupl9xVS2wQ`

Exponent:

`IDAQAB`

(Note that I still didn't get a clear idea of the RSA key strutures. Those above are just a blurry view of a key structure, but for those who interested in, I recommend you to read the [API Documentation "RSAParameters"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) or the [RSA specification](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133))

Obviously what I was doing is to import the entire key string to the `RSAParameters.Modulus`. That is not the way to import the key. So that's why it didn't work.

The way to do it is to extract the `modulus` and `exponent` which was needed for a public encryption from the key file. And import into `RSAParameters`

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
```

Then encrypt the string:

```
RSA.Encrypt("HAHA I GOT IT!!", false);
```

The way to extract. I recommend going to [JavaScience](http://www.jensign.com/) for more info. There are bunch of [cryptographic utilities](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/cryptoutils/index.html) there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for encrypt your string.

```
public string EncodeData(string sData)
{
    try {
        byte[] encData_byte = new byte[sData.Length];
        encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData);
        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
        return encodedData;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and for decrypt your string you can use this code.

```
public string DecodeData(string sData)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
    byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(sData);
    int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
    char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
    utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
    string result = new String(decoded_char);
    return result;
}
```

Try this this will work.

Thank you.

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I need to use key pairs to encrypt data for transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure RSACryptoProvider is working with the key in the format you're providing it in?

A lot of examples of RSACryptoProvider I've seen use XML-based private keys. eg.

[RSA Signing with PHP and verifying with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9633208/569976)

```
"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>3BqiIB3ouyXHDMpW43TlZrx8fkts2FVVARJKNXFRQ/WIlsthDzL2jY2KEJVN6BKE4A51X+8LMzAI+2z3vIgAQT3bRSfOwygpGBjdhhnXJwFlQ6Gf/+z0ffQfVx/DHw3+QWphcwGDBst+KIA6u6ayy+RDE+jEityyyWDiWqkR9J8=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>8a8nuVhIANh7J2TLn4wWTXhZY1tvlyFKaslOeAOVr+wgEWLQpLZ0Jpjm8aUyyOYPXlk7xrA5BOebtz41diu4RQ==</P><Q>6SQ9y3sEMjrf/c4bHGVlhOj4LUVykradWWUNC0ya7llnR8y1djJ1uUut+EoAa1JQCGukuv4K8NvN1Ieo72Fhkw==</Q><DP>cg0VMusNN5DxNRrk2IrUL4TesfuBQpGMO6554DrY1acZTvsRuNj9IQXA3kH2IEYo9H4prk6U6dKeci/iLLze/Q==</DP><DQ>m/pZNXeZ+RkWnrFzxe24m9FZqMAbxThT0Wkf7v1Tcj9yL8EvbmKYDF4riD/KRAMP9HJABbLNExObg6M3TOAz7Q==</DQ><InverseQ>w8PvW8srrPCuOcphBKXSyoZxCZn81+rovBxuE8AB95m5X+URE8SunK7f+g7hBBin6nUOaVGohBP8jzkQEsdx1Q==</InverseQ>  <D>AsVPDypxOJHkLJQLffeFv8JVqt1WNG72j/nj90JC7KEVpBhRU3inw+ZpO4Y1odtB0vQ7pAaFVJKhOlEH2Va48hNUEQujML8rE+LZXgI3lu0TlqOCIqTHIljeJry0ca30XFtFDp9kh0Kr/0CgGMqgIed+hDUjAad8ke9D2YicDok=</D></RSAKeyValue>"
```

Comment: Yes, the code above had successfully encrypted the data, but somehow I just cant decrypt it in PHP. I think it maybe some sort of reverse thing. But I try every combination of reversing the array. Doesn't work.