# ASP.Net equivalent of openssl_private_decrypt and openssl_pkey_get_private

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, encryption, openssl

I want to decrypt text in ASP.Net.

The working code to decrypt the text in PHP is:

```
function rsaDecryption($dataEncrypted, &$dataDecrypted)
{
    // Decrypt argument
    $key = openssl_pkey_get_private(RsaKeyPrivate, RsaKeyPassphrase);
    if (FALSE == $key)
    {
        echo("Failed to get the private key<br />\n");
        return false;
    }
    if(!openssl_private_decrypt($dataEncrypted, $dataDecrypted, $key))
    {
        echo("Failed to decrypt message.<br />\n");
        return false;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I saw several articles on the web, but none was clear to me. This [article (16319559)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319559/encrypt-in-c-sharp-using-rsacryptoserviceprovide-and-decrypt-using-openssl-priva) is the opposite than what I asked, but that was not really clear either.

The private key looks something like this

```
String myPrivateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n<whole bunch of characters>==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What are the equivalent C# methods?

UPDATE:

I created a method using a couple of answers.

Decode string-based key using PEM function, see [here](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20040812-0816.html).

OpenSSL code, DecodeRsaPrivateKey() and GetIntegerSize(), see [here](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs).

I also needed the following:

```
String strArgHtmlDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dataEncrypted);
Byte[] byArgNo64 = Convert.FromBase64String(strArgHtmlDecoded);
```

That results in

```
Byte[] byArgDecrypted = oProviderRsa.Decrypt(byArgNo64, false);
strDecrypted = Encoding.Default.GetString(byArgDecrypted);
```

Comment: I think that I answered my own question using research. Will post my answer shortly after testing, so as to help others.

Comment: Seems to be already solved in http://stackoverflow.com/a/251757/3325704

Comment: That solution combined with another takes me most of the way, just I get an error, see update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

The answer was a collection of code from various places.

The link in the comment was part of it. I saw that same article once before, but without the other code, I did not see the relevance.

See my update for the final answer.

Comment: You should probably put answers in answer blocks, and then accept the answer. That makes it easier on future visitors who learned to use the site that way.